# Is the minimum cost edge in a cycle always in the MST?

Tags: graph-theory

I was doing some practice midterms for an algorithms course I'm taking, and I ran across the following True/False statement:

> Say edge $e$ is the cheapest edge in some cycle of $G$ and all edge weights are distinct. Then $e$ is in the minimum spanning tree of $G$.

I'm unsure of the answer. I know that the cheapest edge in $G$ must be in every minimum spanning tree (assuming all edge costs are distinct), simply because it will be the first edge chosen in an iteration of, say, [Kruskal's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm).

Additionally, I'm aware of the [cycle property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree#Cycle_property) of graphs, which states that the **maximum** cost edge in any cycle must *not* be in any MST (as we can always remove it and add a cheaper edge from that same cycle). But this statement is concerned with the **minimum** cost edge in any cycle.

I'm inclined to say the statement is false simply because I don't know how to prove it for all graphs, but I also can't come up with a counterexample.

I would appreciate any guidance. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you’ve noted, this is False. It’s a bit of a trick question because of your related facts.

[image]

In the above counterexample, 4 is the smallest edge in the 4,5,6 cycle, but it wouldn’t be included in the minimum spanning tree since the 1,2 path is shorter.

Comment: Ah, makes sense! The overlapping cycles seem to be the key to the counterexample. I kept trying to draw cycles that were "by themselves," and couldn't determine a way to not include the minimum cost edge in the cycle. But when two cycles share an edge, the minimum cost edge need not be included in the MST.